# Getting started writing IntelliJ Plugins

Tags: intellij-idea, jython, pycharm

I wish to write a plugin similar to the built-in documentation pane, where you can see the results for a nullege search of the object or method you have selected (same behaviour as the documentation pane) as this would make it far easier to see where you're going wrong when starting out with a new library or framework.

I can see on [the confluence page](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Writing+Plug-ins) how to create a plugin project, and have tried looking at the examples on [jetbrains' github](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins), but I have struggled to see what needs to go where in order to make it work. I've had a google about but there dont seem to be any easily searched resources on this topic - if anyone has done plugin development for the intelliJ platform and can give me some pointers, they'd be much appreciated.

Comment: The [guide here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Getting+Started+with+Plugin+Development) is pretty straightforward. What specific problems do you have with it?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Mainly that I couldn't find it ;) Cheers - I'll take a look at it, and if it doesn't need any extra explanation I'd really appreciate you making that comment an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Confluence page linked in your question has this guide referenced at the bottom, weird that you didn't find it.

Comment: :s looks like it's a touch of the brain fade - I should probably just delete this question unless I come across any friction worth documenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jetbrains.org](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Writing+Plug-ins) leads you to the docs & the [wiki page for plugin development](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment) is quite handy.

Comment: now all I could do with is some docs on the `com.jetbrains.python` api, doesn't look like those exist though. Far too used to python where is sort of info is freely available...

Comment: yeah, maybe should ping the devs at jetbrains forums for more info - they are usually quite reactive answering the questions on their forum, so give it a shot.